# How to use downloaded fonts in PyCharm 2019.1?

Tags: fonts, pycharm

I'm using the Pycharm IDE for python, in version 2019.1, and while there is a font management section in the settings menu it seems I can only use Windows' default fonts..
I've downloaded fonts specifically to use them in the editor, but thay aren't showing up in the dropdown menu. And checking the "Use custom fonts" box doesn't fix it.

Apparently in previous versions there was a clear option to use downloaded fonts, but it looks like it's not there anymore. Does anyone know how to use downloaded fonts, if at all possible?
PyCharm is such a complete and convenient IDE, I would be extremely surprised if something as trivial and commonplace as using downloaded fonts can't be done. I will survive if it's not possible, but that would be a bit lame.

[Running winver on the console opens this window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fmMq7.png)

Comment: Are you running Windows 10?  If you are, what version of Windows 10 are you running, this information should be provided in the question body not with a comment.

Comment: I added the info.

Comment: It’s unclear which edition your referring to when you indicate it’s “Windows 10 Family”, to my knowledge, that isn’t an edition that Microsoft sells.  Use **winver** to identify the edition.

Comment: Winver still says "Windows 10 family", but if that's confusing I'll remove it. I put exactly what winver returned.

Comment: It would be wonderful if you provided a screenshot of that information.  Remove any personal information you feel necessary

Comment: Oh I guess it only said "family" when the system language was French, I just changed it to english so that's why :/